# improving "apply understanding about A to examine B"

Tags: expressions, writing

(after I wrote sentences in which I discuss about occupational freedom, I wrote the sentence like the below)

> I apply these understanding about an occupational freedom to examine
>   the constitutionality of Japanese law school’s current admission
>   system.

1) I'm concerned if "apply understanding about A to examine B" sounds awkward.

Could you teach me how to express this better?

2) I feel weird about putting "an" before freedom since it's constitutional right.

3) I repeat using the term "law school's admission system" because I can't find any expression that can replace "system".

If there exists such expression, please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apply these understanding about an occupational freedom to examine the constitutionality of Japanese law school’s current admission system.

Correction: **I apply this understanding of "occupational freedom" to examining the constitutionality of Japanese law schools' current admission system.**

the idiomatic way to understanding: to have an understanding of something.
However, since  you have **this understanding**, you do not need a.

occupational freedom? Freedom to choose an occupation? I would use quotes since this doesn't exist in Western law....

- more than one school, right?